# Private forum /guestbook to coordinate rides for PHP password protected wedding website

Tags: php, forum

I created a simple private PHP website for my wedding guests. The website is a single PHP page that prompts the user for a password that was snail-mailed to them with our invitations.  If the correct password is entered, the PHP page serves up the HTML content which is otherwise inaccessible to the web. It works great!

Now, though, I would like to add a forum, guestbook or some other method for guests to post their travel plans or requests rides from the airport and such. Any solution ideally would be:

- **Private** so that people feel comfortable posting cell phones or travel information
- **Simple** for less tech savy guests to use (e.g. no captchas, no email confirmations, no registration)
- **Easy for me to setup** I would like to avoid setting up MySQL on the server if possible.

Things I looked into but gave up on:

- **Using a Google Docs spreadsheet**  is too difficult because it would require me to solicit email addresses from every guest and then manually invite them to the doc. Any solution should be accessible via a link from my password protected wedding website.
- **[NoNonesense Forum](http://forum.camendesign.com/)** This php forum looked promising  but it would be very hard to make private from the broader web.
- **phpBB** and other more powerful fourms. These are too complicated, and not obviously private either.
- **[Rideshare.us](http://www.rideshare.us/)** This service is close, but its a little complicated and kludgy and it really takes people away to a complicated website. I'm wondering if I can do better, especially for less savvy users.

Comment: phpbb can be made private, and most cms engines will do this. If you don't want sql.. then choose a HTML CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not throw a simple WordPress installation up there, password-protect the page/post in question and then turn comments on?  Instant private discussion board, takes maybe 15 minutes to set up.